# Loading an image programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage

In my App for the iPad I'm trying to load an image file programmatically. The file is NOT part of my project, hence it is not referenced in XCode. There is no entry for the file in XCode's Groups and Files column.

The image has to be loaded at runtime instead, it name being read from a Property List.

I'm trying to load the file like this:

```
NSString* pathToImageFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyImage" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"MyDirectory"];
UIImage* retVal = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToImageFile];
```

In this case, `mydirectory` lives in the main bundle like this:

```
MyAmazingApp.app/MyDirectory/MyImage.png
```

Unfortunately, the Image will not load. I can't add the image file to my project, as its name is to be determined at runtime and cannot be known in advance. The file name is read from a config file (a Property List) at runtime instead.

What am I doing wrong? Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: How is `MyImage.png` getting in `MyAmazingApp.app` if it isn't being copied over via XCode?

Comment: Stephen: copied manually. I'm just trying to find out how I can decouple content from code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by decoupling content from code.  Files on the iPhone are either in your sandbox, main gallery, or installed with XCode/app.

Comment: @MattiasC, also, just because you copied it into the `/build/` directory, doesn't mean it was installed on the Simulator or Device.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani: Thanks for your help, Stephen. Things are getting clearer now. Here's some more information: By "decoupling code from content" I mean that I'm trying to write an app which should be able to play content which will be delivered via a web service, for instance, or via an in-app-purchase. It will have to display image files of which the names and boundaries are unknown at the time of coding and I'm now just trying to read a file name from a Plist and then load the relevant file. I hope that this makes it clearer. And again, thanks for your comments and your help so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSFileManager to get the contents of a directory, or several directories. You obviously have to know *something* about the file you want to load so that you can identify it, but you could for example use NSFileManager to help you generate a list of images in your app bundle and in your app's Documents directory.